# Cannot upgrade pyzmq on Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pyzmq

I try to upgrade the pyzmq (17.0.0) library in Google Colaboratory to a newer version. I used the command `!pip install pyzmq`, which installs the latest pyzmq version (18.0.1). Then, I have to restart the runtime to be able to use the newly installed version, but I cannot reconnect to the runtime after that. Do you know why is this happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Please be more specific on what you want to achieve. If you need help with that you can read this guide: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

`pyzmq` is used in the operation of the backend, so it's possible that the upgrade introduces an incompatibility with the Colab plumbing.

As a work-around, I'd recommend installing `pyzmq` and whatever library requires the upgrade in a virtualenv in order to isolate it from the system Python used by Colab.